# Android Market web store with OTA installations

Tags: android

Now that android has a [web store](http://www.engadget.com/2011/02/02/android-market-gets-a-web-store/) I was wondering how is this done and how this thing works internally? I think this is really awesome. Is this available on the SDK's? Are all android versions supported?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not about SDK.
There's `Android Cloud to device messaging`. you have to get that app on your phone, and the webstore sends the market link to the APK , OTA to your phone, because your phone has that app.
Then your phone knows how to interpret that URL and install an app.

Similar to this, we already had `Chrome to Phone` thingie.

**UPDATE:** Thats something which needed some experiments. I just tried to install an app on my phone. Market Webstore asked me to sign-in and after signing in, I could see all the apps that I currently have on my phone. looks like my google account was recording that too. As I clicked the install button,  Market said the app will be downloaded on my phone.

Looks like it has marked that app for installation in my google account, and when my account is synced on phone, the phone will realize that it has to download this app and will download it.
But, as of now, nothing seems to be happening.

**UPDATE:** Damn! The download started! There were two options in the market webstore about the device you wish to install it to, and don't know why, both of them  were 'phone'.

I selected the upper option, and download started almost instantly, AND **Silently**
thus, you get your answer. silent installs are there.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me man. How about the silent installation of the applications? Is this also within Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't heard about silent installation yet.. tell me more about it!

Comment: If you try to install applications through the webstore, it will be downloaded and installed in your mobile silently. All left for you is a notification that the application is installed successfully. How is this possible?

Comment: Awesome isn't it? But how is it done programmatically? That is the question =)

Comment: I still feel that cloud-to-device messaging works behind the scene for this.

Comment: *It's not Android Cloud to Device Messaging.* It's a feature introduced in Froyo, and the OTA installation works perfectly in Eclair devices, like mine.

Comment: Yes, you're right. but `Google Talk Service` has always been there which has been doing all the stuff like 'push' notifications before froyo as well. In froyo they only opened it to  third party developers with the name C2DM